# How can I do two columns in OpenOffice.org Writer?

Tags: openoffice, documents, layout, word-processing, openoffice-writer

I would like to structure my document with two columns in the middle of the page, and one column in the top and in the bottom. Like my example below. How can I do two columns like this in OpenOffice.org Writer?

```
My document My document My document My document My
 document My document My document My document My 
document My document

My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document
My document My document   My document My document

My document My document My document My document My
 document My document My document My document My 
document My document
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type the first bit of text normally.  Then, go to the Insert menu, choose Section, click on the Columns tab, and then choose two columns.

That will give you two columns just for that section, rather than for the entire page.

Comment: Holy damn! I have been trying a long time to finagle something with "Format > Columns". The unintuitive nature of the WhatYouSeeIsAllYouGet (aka MustPutManipulationsSomewhereIntoAMenu) interface strikes again...