# Creating columns in OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: openoffice, text-formatting, openoffice-writer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do two columns in OpenOffice.org Writer?](https://superuser.com/questions/141755/how-can-i-do-two-columns-in-openoffice-org-writer)

How do I create two columns in OpenOffice.org Writer so that I can type in and easily move back and forth between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You could use frames, "Insert" >> "Frames"